# Best practise for placing custom Entity methods in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating Symfony project. And now I'm trying to find best practice for   adding custom methods.. What is yours?

---

*Visual explanation:*

`users` table

```
id | name | surname
---+------+--------
1  | John | Smith
2  | Matt | Malone
```

`Entity\User.php`

```
namespace TestBundle\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=36)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * OneToMany
     */
    private $userCompanies;

    {{ Setters and Getters }}
}
```

Where I should store custom method, like:

```
function getFullName()
{
     return sprintf("%s %s", $this->getName(), $this->getSurname());
}
```

Or more complex:

```
function getCurrentUserCompany()
{
    foreach ($this->getUserCompanies() as $company) {
        if ($company->isActive()) {
            return $company;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Please note, that all data returned via `JSON`

So far I tried extending `class`, but `annotations` not working as expected. Placing custom `methods` in same file looks trashy, since there will be more than one of them.

But.. but if there is `repositoryClass` - maby there is place for custom `methods` as well?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as "custom" methods. Classes are about encapsulating the data and the logic, and you are in control of what API you want to expose. Doctrine entities are no exception. For example, if it doesn't make sense in your application to have individual getFirstName() and getLastName() methods, you could just as well choose to only have a getFullName() method.

Answer (score 3):

If it's about methods that are used mainly for display purposes then they are very similar to the getters, in my opinion they best fit is in the Entity itself, so inside your User.php class.

The repository is for defining methods for getting the entity from your storage level (DB, cache...), but the view level (your twig) should take the data from the entity itself.

If you need something more complicated or you need to reuse it, like a date filter, then it's better to create a Twig extension.

Comment: For the twig filter I find it also depends. If you are going to use it on all dates (ie: multiple entities) sure, but if it is specific to the Entity you can just as well create a method inside it.

Comment: Thanks for `Twig` extension idea, but `project === API`, and all data returned via `JSON`. `getFullName` `getter` is only example, I do have more complicated functions inside, like get user current company (user can have multiple), get user badges, etc..

Comment: What if you need to perform some action to entities? For example, $user->doSomethingToThisUser()? I find it hard to put in the Entity, since doctrine is not available, unless I inject it...

Comment: You can use something like that: `$service->doSomethingToThisUser($user)`

Answer (score 1):

Methods like that belong to entity class and there is no reason to split code. If many entity classes share some methods, you can always create shared base abstract class or trait for them.

If you really want separated files for sake of your aesthetic, then use traits, but remember that it's not proper and conventional use of them.